# cannot import name 'imagenet_utils' from 'tensorflow.keras.applications'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

i have the following python imports with in Jupyter Notebook.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.applications import imagenet_utils
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import itertools
import os
import shutil
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
```

But i keep getting the following error

ImportError: cannot import name 'imagenet_utils' from 'tensorflow.keras.applications' (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\api_v2\keras\applications_*init*_.py)

when i search for **cannot import name 'imagenet_utils' from 'tensorflow.keras.applications' **in google i dont get much helpful information.

Has anyone come across this at all?

Answer (score 2):

change

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications import imagenet_utils
```

to

```
from keras.applications import imagenet_utils
```

Answer (score 0):

i managed to solve my issue.

first i ran the following to update all modules.

conda update --all

Then i used 'from keras.applications import imagenet_utils'

instead of '#from tensorflow.keras import imagenet_utils'